# How can I add a number twice after every 6 rows?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on installment plan. Lets suppose we have a plan of 1,250,000 with 35 installments and payment frequency is after 1 month.

customer has to pay 5% extra after every 6 months. So regularly he will pay 1% and after every 6 months he will pay 6%.

So suppose after other payment charges we have payment of 812,500 that is 65% of total payment.

Now every 6th month customer will pay 1% of regular fee with 5% extra that is 62500.

For clearfication see screenshot. Currently I have to manually add that values but I need to automate this process to save time.

[image]

Comment: Nice screencap; now where's the code for it? and the tags used.

Comment: Seems somewhat related to a previous question you posted http://stackoverflow.com/q/43134885/1415724

Answer (score 1):

you can use the mod operator to find every 6th row like this .

```
for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){ 
    if($i%6 == 0)
        echo $i;
}
```